# Неправильно отображается язык на сайте

Tags: веб-программирование

Скопировал я сайт *curren1.best-gooods.ru* через *teleport pro*.
Залил на хостинг (адрес — http://curren.96.lt/), а он отображается неправильно.

Я в этом деле новичок, подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить.

Отсюда же вытекает вопрос: как мне сделать, чтобы заказы приходили на мой e-mail адрес, а не на адрес создателя сайта?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас проблема с кодировкой. Исправьте строку в вашем файле "<meta charset=utf-8"utf-8">" на <meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
Плюс сами файлы сайта тоже должны быть сохранены в utf-8 кодировке перед заливкой на сайт.

Comment: Спасибо большое)
Еще один вопрос остался:как мне сделать чтобы заказы приходили на мой e-mail адрес,а не на адрес создателя сайта.
Если и с этим поможете,то цены вам не будет :)

Comment: У меня кнопка заказать на вашем сайте не срабатывает, это так, для справки. Но, судя по всему, вам нужно покопаться в файле order.php и посмотреть, что там, скорее всего, email задан где-то там.

Comment: Спасибо,буду искать :)
Точно,я даже не заметил,что не срабатывает.
Не знаете в чем может быть дело?

Comment: Не знаю, я толком не разбирался - у вас там бардак в коде. Но как я догадываюсь, при клике на кнопку должна всплывать форма, которую клиент должен заполнить. Но форма не всплывает, следовательно, нужно смотреть, что за обработчик висит на кнопке и почему ничего не работает. Поэтому мой вам совет: прежде чем что-то пытаться отладить, наведи в коде порядок.